# Define dummy columns for each day of year BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of a similar format

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 |

And I would like to add a day of the year dummy column for each day in 2020 similar to the table below. If the date entry for a row is Jan 1 2020 for example, then the dummy column for that day takes a 1, else 0. My data spans all of 2020 so I would need 366 columns. Is it possible to do this with some sort of loop (and avoid a bunch of case whens) ?

| ID | date | 2020_01_01 | 2020-01-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: @Alexander van oostenrijk thanks for the edits

Comment: This sounds like a very poor design, WHY are you trying to accomplish that???

Comment: you mean query results? and this sounds like a PIVOT.

Comment: @MatBailie I need to get a count for each day for each ID. So the idea is to define these dummy columns and aggregate the data at the ID level with SUM of the dummies to generate the count

Comment: Pivotting this to one column per date is a very VERY bad code-smell / anti-pattern... What's wrong with a straight aggregate? `SELECT date, id, COUNT(*) FROM yourTable GROUP BY date, id`  That retains the normalised structure inherently present in the SQL language and the database engines.  Your description is equivalent to asking how to fit a square peg in a round hole; the answer to which is `don't`.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @MatBailie the table I'm trying to join this with lives at the the unique ID level (out of my control, that's just how it is given to me) and your solution does not. Thanks though

Comment: Just because the table you're trying to join against exists at the id level does not preclude you joining against a normalised result set.  I strongly suggest stepping back one level and describing the wider context; once you do the join as described, what do you want to do with That result?  You may find we can offer you patterns for dealing with that.  Believing your wider problem can ***only*** be solved by pivoting to 365/366 columns suggests a faulty assumption somewhere.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks, yeah I just reshaped (pivoted) the output of this table wide in another language and it worked just fine. Thanks for the help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just reshaped (pivoted) the output of this table wide in another language and it worked just fine

Consider pivot approach available in BigQuery - let's start with just simplified example data you have in your question

```
select * from (
  select *, replace(cast(date as string), '-', '_') col
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
pivot(count(col) as _ for col in ('2020_01_01', '2020_01_02'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Obviously, if you have whole year of dates - you don't want to type all 360+ columns - in such cases you can use `execute immediate` as in below example

```
execute immediate (select '''
  select * from (
    select *, replace(cast(date as string), '-', '_') col
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
  pivot(count(col) as _ for col in (''' || string_agg(concat('"', replace(cast(day as string), '-', '_'), '"')) || '''))
'''
from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')) day
)
```

this will return as many those expected 360+ column for each day or 2020 year like in below example

[image]